# solrj search on particular field

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am using solrj to perform a query search from solr installation.

This is what i have:

```
public List<Details> search(String query, int first, int rows) {
    List<Details> cds = new ArrayList<Details>();
    try {
      SolrQuery q = new SolrQuery();
      q.set("q", "name:" + query); //this throws an error on the solr side!
      q.setFields("id");
      q.setRows(rows);
      q.setStart(first);
      QueryResponse r = server.query(q);
      final SolrDocumentList docList = r.getResults();
      for (SolrDocument doc : docList) {
        String id_ = doc.getFieldValue("id").toString();
        Long id = Long.parseLong(id_);
        Details cd = detailsFacade.find(id);
        cds.add(cd);
      }
    } catch (SolrServerException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(SolrIndexer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return cds;
  }

  public int count(String query) {
    try {
      SolrQuery q = new SolrQuery();
      q.set("q", "name:" + query); //this throws an error on the solr side
      q.setRows(0);  // don't actually request any data
      return (int) server.query(q).getResults().getNumFound();
    } catch (SolrServerException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(SolrIndexer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

I want to do a query on the name field only. (I have several fields with data for the indexed documents).

The error on the solr side:

```
1126326 [qtp1645986986-17] ERROR org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'name:': Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 5.
Was expecting one of:
    <BAREOPER> ...
    "(" ...
    "*" ...
    <QUOTED> ...
    <TERM> ...
    <PREFIXTERM> ...
    <WILDTERM> ...
    <REGEXPTERM> ...
    "[" ...
    "{" ...
    <LPARAMS> ...
    <NUMBER> ...

    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:171)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1859)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:721)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:417)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'name:': Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 5.
Was expecting one of:
    <BAREOPER> ...
    "(" ...
    "*" ...
    <QUOTED> ...
    <TERM> ...
    <PREFIXTERM> ...
    <WILDTERM> ...
    <REGEXPTERM> ...
    "[" ...
    "{" ...
    <LPARAMS> ...
    <NUMBER> ...

    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.parse(SolrQueryParserBase.java:157)
    at org.apache.solr.search.LuceneQParser.parse(LuceneQParser.java:50)
    at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:142)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:142)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.parser.ParseException: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 5.
Was expecting one of:
    <BAREOPER> ...
    "(" ...
    "*" ...
    <QUOTED> ...
    <TERM> ...
    <PREFIXTERM> ...
    <WILDTERM> ...
    <REGEXPTERM> ...
    "[" ...
    "{" ...
    <LPARAMS> ...
    <NUMBER> ...

    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.generateParseException(QueryParser.java:651)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.jj_consume_token(QueryParser.java:533)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:217)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:108)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:97)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.parse(SolrQueryParserBase.java:153)
    ... 34 more
```

How can i achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The error is on the line

```java
q.set("q", "name:" + query); //this throws an error on the solr side
```

You must remove this line and simply call

```java
q.setQuery(query);
```

This suppose that the specified query is well formed such as described [on the solr query syntax wiki page](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax). For example in your situation, the query must be something like :

```
name:"Jackson"
```

The set(name, values...) method can be used if you want to build the query programmatically like this :

```java
q.set("name", "Jackson");
```

Comment: I would go for `q.set("name", "Jackson");`. In addition consider using `org.apache.solr.client.solrj.util.ClientUtils#escapeQueryChars` to escape special characters a user may give as input to a query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SolrRequestParsers.parseQueryString(string)`](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_7_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/servlet/SolrRequestParsers.html#parseQueryString%28java.lang.String%29), as shown below:

```
MultiMapSolrParams solrParams = SolrRequestParsers.parseQueryString("q=name:abc");
QueryResponse r = server.query(solrParams, SolrRequest.METHOD.POST);
```

Hope this helps you.